# Django how to implement a one-to-many self-dependent foreign key

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am implementing a User referral system, which existing users can refer other people to register an account with the link they provided. After the new user registers, the new user will be stored to the field 'referred_who' of the existing user.

I have tried using the following method:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    ...
    referred_who = models.ManyToManyField('self', blank=True, symmetrical=False)

class ReferralAward(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        referral_id = self.request.GET['referral_id']
        current_referred = self.request.GET['referred']
        // referrer
        user = get_user_model().objects.filter(referral_id=referral_id)
        // user being referred
        referred_user = get_user_model().objects.filter(username=current_referred)

        for item in user:
            previous_referred = item.referred_who
        previous_referred.add(referred_user[0])
        user.update(referred_who=previous_referred)
```

And I got the following error:

```
Cannot update model field <django.db.models.fields.related.ManyToManyField: referred_who> (only non-relations and foreign keys permitted).
```

I am not sure if this method even works. I have check the Django Admin backend and I realized the 'Referred who' field actually contains all the users. It seems that it only highlightes the user being referred instead of only showing the referred users.

Also, I tried to access the 'referred_who' field in the back-end and it returns 'None'.

Is there a way to stored the users in the 'referred_who' field so that I can see all of the user being referred and access them in the back-end? For instance:

```
referral_id = self.request.GET['referral_id']
user = get_user_model().objects.filter(referral_id=referral_id)
print(user[0].referred_who)
```

Can someone show me a better way to do it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I would suggest you to change model to have a `referred_by` field with `ForeignKey` to `self`. So every user will store a user who referred them and with `related_name` you can access all invited users list by a particular user.

Comment: Hello, could you explain what does related_name mean? How does it help me to get who the current user has referred? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You ask how to create a 1-Many field, but in your models you're trying to create m2m. Just change field to FK.

`referred_who = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True)`.

In case you need to have multiple fks to the same model, you need to specify `related_name` as well. You can use name of the field for it. More in [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name).